# How do I use a check_box_tag for value that isn't a boolean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a field in my database called property_types which has a string value and the values can be "Condo" or "Single Family Home" or "Commercial". I want to display each property type in the user's search form with a check box next to each property type so the user can select which property types should be included in their search results.

But if the property_type field is not a boolean and it has several possible values how do I do this using check_box_tag which can only have a true or false value?

EDIT:

I added this checkbox code to properties/index where the search form is and the search results are displayed:

```
<%= check_box_tag(:condo, value = "1", checked = true) %>
```

In  properties_controller I added this:

```
@properties = @properties.where(:property_type => "Condo") if params[:condo].present?
```

Ofcourse it doesn't work because I haven't got a clue what I'm doing but is this along the right lines or not?

Comment: Can it be more than one value/string?

Comment: no each property has only one value, ie "Condo"

Comment: I mean, can the user select more than one option?

Comment: ah I see, yes the user can select all the options if he wants but must have a minimum of one option selected

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at you requirements i would suggest you to leave the values at `true` and `false`, and on your controller, when you persist the object, you check all possibilities that are checked (`true`) and put you `project_types` attribute together.

```
project_types += 'condo&' if params[:condo]
project_types += 'commercial&' if params[:commercial]
...
```

Of course the `&` i put in the examples are just for demonstration, as i don't know how you would create this string.

EDIT:

Well, maybe you should refactor your model. I believe it would be easier if the `project_types` attribute didn't exist, and instead, you had several boolean attributes named after your strings. Then you can search like this:

```
@properties.where(:condo => params[:condo], :commercial => params[:commercial])
```

And it would be easier to understand the code.

Comment: Edited the answer with more info.